# Set UITabBarItem without affecting self.title

Tags: ios, uitabbar

How would I set the `UITabBarItem` and the view controller title separately?

Currently I am using the following to set the title of the view controller:

```
self.title = @"Title Text";
```

This is great, however it is affecting the text on the tab bar item as well. How would I target the `UITabBar`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBarItem.title = @"...";
```

Comment: Can you provide more code please? And are you using storyboard?

Comment: Add code to you question. From where you implement the TabBarController and the ViewController you want to change the title from. We can just guess otherwise

Answer (score 0):

To set a separate title:

```
self.tabBarItem.title = @"myTitle";
```

Place the code within this initializer, it is in the class by default (at top of the page):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self){
    self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"myTitle" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
}

return self;
```

}

Comment: self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"myTitle" image:image tag:2]; If this does not work add a piece of code to your question.

Comment: Doesn't work. What code could I add? I am putting that in my viewdidload. Should it be in the app delegate?

Comment: Place the code in the same class in: - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{} between the if brackets. It won't work in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   self.navigationController.title = @"My UITabBarItem Title =)";
}
```